# Add a folder to the Python library path, once for all (Windows)

Tags: python, path, environment-variables, anaconda

I use

```
sys.path.append('D:/my_library_folder/')
import mymodule
```

in order to import some module.

How to add *permanently* this folder `D:/my_library_folder/` to the Python library path, so that I will be able to use **only**

```
import mymodule
```

in the future?

(Even after a reboot, etc.)

Comment: put the folder in sitepackages directory

Comment: thank you. I will do a symbolic link of my folder in `site-packages`.

Comment: also you might need to add an empty file `__init__.py` to the folder.

Comment: yes I just noticed that 2 minutes ago ;) (`__init__.py`)  thanks!

Comment: if you copy/paste your solution @suhail into an answer, I can accept it as answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

just put the folder in `site-packages` directory. ie:

```
C:\PythonXY\Lib\site-packages
```

Note: you need to add an empty file `__init__.py` to the folder

---

**Files named `__init__.py` are used to mark directories on disk as a Python package directories.**

If you have the files:

```
C:\PythonXY\Lib\site-packages\<my_library_folder>\__init__.py
C:\PythonXY\Lib\site-packages\<my_library_folder>\module.py
```

you can import the code in module.py as:

```
from <my_library_folder> import module
```

If you remove the `__init__.py` file, Python will no longer look for submodules inside that directory, so attempts to import the module will fail.

If you have lots of folders, then create the empty `__init__.py` file in each folder. for eg:

```
C:\PythonXY\Lib\site-packages\<my_library_folder>\
    __init__.py
    module.py        
    subpackage\
        __init__.py
        submodule1.py
        submodule2.py
```

Answer (score 5):

Set PYTHONPATH environment variable to D:/my_library_folder/

Comment: http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html both support PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 2):

If `D:/my_library_folder` is a project you're working on and has a setup script, you could also do `python setup.py develop`.  Not entirely related to the question, but I also recommend using [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/).