# Python: using a copy of a library source files instead of installing it

Tags: python, package

As I don't have the permission to install Python packages, and I need to use an external library, I am trying to copy all the source files from an installed version of that package in a folder and then use those files instead of installing the package. Also I don't want to use virtual environment for this task.

So this is what I have done:

1. I have installed the library, lets call it `external_lib` on a machine that I have permission to install it.
2. I have copied all the files of that library to a folder; lets call it `ext_lib_folder`, that is at the same level of my Python code (that is going to use that library).
3. I have added this to my python code:

   ```
   import sys, os

   file_path = 'ext_lib_folder/'

   sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(file_path))

   import external_lib
   ```

But when I try to run the code I get error as:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ext_lib._abcfunpy'; 'ext_lib' is not a package
```

what is the reason for the error? How can I do what I want to do correctly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20394613/add-a-folder-to-the-python-library-path-once-for-all-windows and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path?rq=1 might help

Comment: And you can't use "pip install --user" to install as a non-admin?

Comment: @Alan, I want to know if it is possible without your suggestion. Although I also tried 
`pip install --user ext_lib` and give me this error `no such option --user`

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of how to do this with selenium. I saved the library to a folder "C:/Py" along with `geckodriver.exe`

```
import sys, os
file_path = 'C:\\Py\\selenium'
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(file_path))
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

service = Service('C:\\Py\\geckodriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Comment: so why do I get the errors I mentioned?

Comment: I am unsure, something to do with the difference between `import external_lib ` and `from external_lib import ....`