# access function from a different subfolder in python project

Tags: python

I have a python project with the following structure:

```
project_folder/
    __init__.py
    subfolder/
        __init__.py
        main.py
        generate_values.py
    lib/
        __init__.py
        external.py
```

where I am running `subfolder/main.py`, and it internally calls `generate_values.py`.
Inside `generate_values.py` I am calling the function calculate_external from `lib/external.py`.

The original code was:
`from lib.external import calculate_external`
this was working when the main and generate_values py files were not in a subfolder.

but now I get the error
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib'`

after some research i tried the following but still got errors:

1. `from project_folder.lib.external import calculate_external` -->
   `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project_folder'`
2. `from ..lib.external import calculate_external` -->
   `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Any help in resolving this would be great.

Note that the main and generate_values must stay in a subfolder, because there will be different such subfolders that do different things but all use the lib folder.

Comment: Try setting your 'lib' path to your python path. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20394613/add-a-folder-to-the-python-library-path-once-for-all-windows

Comment: thanks. is it a good solution if i run it in a cloud instance though? might need permission etc., no?

Comment: you can use sys.path.append(folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to [@Jason Chia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12085772/jason-chia) and [@Wonka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5226792/wonka) this is a working solution:

in the generate_values.py file do:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("project_folder")
from lib.external import calculate_external
```